# Redirect into fecth/asyncData not work 100% with vuex-persistedstate

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

#### Version

[v1.4.0](https://github.com/nuxt.js/releases/tag/v1.4.0)

#### Reproduction link

https://github.com/furyscript/nuxt-redirect-error

#### Steps to reproduce

You need to login, go to inspire page and make sure the first http call is a 200 request. After that try to refresh page (F5 into /inspire) until the http call return a 401 error, so you see that you return to home and not in login page.

#### What is expected ?

It's expected to go into login page without flickering and back to the page.

#### What is actually happening?

I already opened an issue to `vuex-persistedstate` but he says that is a problem of nuxt.
Related: https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/issues/143

---

Someone can help me? Thanks.